# OnClick method doesn't activate while using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick

While using google maps in my android application I have come uppon a problem:

I want to move the camera and zoom when clicking on a textView (activates moveToSlo method).

The method is this:

```
public void moveToSlo(View v){
    slovenia = new LatLng(46.1491664, 14.9860106);
    slo = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(slovenia,8);
    map.moveCamera(slo);
}
```

but It says that it cannot resolve moveCamera method.

I am probably missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(slovenia, 8));
```

and double check that you initialize your mapFragment like this

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

And then get the map itself

```
map = fm.getMap();
```

Comment: Are map.animateCamera and map.moveCamera the same, or is one instantaneous and the other one incremental?

I already initialize the map fragment onCreate:
"map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        map.getMapAsync(this);   <--- this part, no idea what it does.
"
in onMapReady(GoogleMap map) the map.moveCamera works great.

but if in the previous method I use GoogleMap map instead of View v, it crashes.

Comment: Try to initialize map as in the example above to make sure that you don't misuse mapFragment and map.

Comment: Workista! Tnx a million!